# How do I create ABI encoded constructor argument to verify an Ehtereum contract on etherscan.io when i know the arguments: adress1 uint

Tags: etherscan, verify

I have a contract:
https://github.com/slavik0329/BetterAuction
that i want to verify here:
https://etherscan.io/verifyContract?a=0x3e7a000DC9FE17424cBA7E5bB21390A87a8e32d6
the arguments are:

0xb7cf43651d8f370218cF92B00261cA3e1B02Fda0

0x60CE2769E5d330303Bd9Df88F7b843A40510F173

0x7422B53EB5f57AdAea0DdffF82ef765Cfbc4DBf0

1800

100000

how do i create the ABI-encoded constructor arguments?
This does not work:
00000000000000000000000xb7cf43651d8f370218cF92B00261cA3e1B02Fda000000000000000000000000x60CE2769E5d330303Bd9Df88F7b843A40510F17300000000000000000000000x7422B53EB5f57AdAea0DdffF82ef765Cfbc4DBf000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

000000000000000000000000b7cf43651d8f370218cF92B00261cA3e1B02Fda000000000000000000000000060CE2769E5d330303Bd9Df88F7b843A40510F1730000000000000000000000007422B53EB5f57AdAea0DdffF82ef765Cfbc4DBf0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000070800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000186a0

Two changes with respect to your version:

- Removal of the leading 0x from the addresses
- I'm assuming your last two parameters are decimal 1800 and 100000, which are 0x708 and 0x186a0 respectively in hex. If they are already hex then change them back in the above.

Comment: thanks i learned two things, but unfortunately the contract does not verify. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Well, looking at the [initial deployment transcation](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1fc5219414a38f0099b689ecf36a04de006656fe3f080b3fe013d96a9e72376a) for the contract, it seems that bidding period was set to 1125 (0x465) rather than 1800 (0x708) as you stated above. So try replacing "708"  with "465". The other thing to check is the precise compiler version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an online tool https://abi.hashex.org to generate ABI-encoded constructor argument, it will automatically produce result, just pick Function type constructor and enter parameter types and their values.