# How get Constructor Arguments ABI-encoded?

Tags: abi

Im trying to verify an ETH contract, but I complete the etherscan form to and i receive this message:

"**Error! Unable to verify source code
Missing Constructor Arguments for function JL(uint256 initialSupply, string tokenName, string tokenSymbol)**"

My contract was created using https://remix.ethereum.org/ On this link are my smart contract code 
- JLC.json
- JLC.sol
 https://gist.github.com/5067bbba4b0640e5679d85f8625c198e

Im new on this and im just testing how smart contracts work.

I hope your support guys.

Thanks.

Comment: This link following https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi

Answer (score 18):

You can use simple online tool to get abi-encoded constructor parameters https://abi.hashex.org. Just paste in abi and enter parameter values. Abi-encoded parameters would be automatically calculated.

Then just copy and paste result into etherscan.io constructor parameters input.

Here is an example of using this tool
[image]

Comment: do you an idea how that can be done programmatically using web3 ?

Comment: It could be done programmatically with this library: https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi. Or you can take a look at this method: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#soliditysha3

Answer (score 2):

If your contract was created by another contract, the transaction detail may not have an easy way to get the constructor arguments in ABI-encoded form. In this case I recommend using the web3 abi functions for this purpose like `web3.eth.abi.encodeParameters`.

- https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-abi.html#encodeparameters
- You can run these functions from the web console in http://remix.ethereum.org/

Answer (score 0):

to verify your contract you just need the JLC.sol exactly the same when was deployed. by the way, you can see your ABI code in the remix click in on compile > details button

Comment: I try. But i cannt identify the constructor arguments on ABI code. I have understood that constructor arguments should be something like this: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002540be400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000044e4154410000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000044e41544100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 0):

You can get the constructor arguments **from the deployment transaction**. For example, I deployed my contract at https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x3b0110386e5409a81548beed2020ab3d12f221357905802a2eaf5f7a9d594e52 and last 64 chars of **Input Data** have the right Constructor Arguments (ABI-encoded).

This rule is valid in my contract because constructor requires just 1 parameter: an address => function Asset(address _SCIssuers) => https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xefb27d9eaa381e958319052dd274c9866f5abc8c#code